# Insert ImageView inside ListItem

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview

I have the following code which show me a listitem with name, score, sex, age and country:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="2.0" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_last_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this code looks like:
[image]

What I want to do now is to add an image profile and show the list item like following:

[image]

How could I modify my code to adapt the imageview. I have tryied several configuration of ImageView with no succes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="2.0" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_last_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this..